# Property `default` is not declared configurable when mocking React component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs

I just started a new React/Next.js project and realized that I cannot mock memoized React components the way I could in a previous project. And I fail to find out why. Here's a minimal example of my setup:

```js
// /src/components/Foo.tsx

import Bar from "./Bar";

const Foo = () => (
  <div>
    <Bar />
  </div>
);
export default Foo;
```

```js
// /src/components/Bar.tsx

import { memo } from "react";

const Bar = memo(function Bar_() {
  return <div>Original</div>;
});

export default Bar;
```

Now I want to test `Foo` mocking `Bar`.

This is what I did in my last project:

```js
// /src/components/Foo.test.tsx

import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Foo from "./Foo";

const barModule = require("./Bar");
jest.replaceProperty(barModule, "default", () => <div>Mocked</div>);

describe("Foo", () => {
  it("should mock Bar", () => {
    render(<Foo />);

    expect(screen.queryByText("Original")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

But when I run the tests, I get the error message "Property `default` is not declared configurable". How can I fix this?

Here are my config files:

```js
// jest.config.js

const nextJest = require("next/jest");

/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: "./",
});

/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(config);
```

```js
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

```js
// package.json

{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.1.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.1.4",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can probably avoid this by not using default exports. Using default exports across module systems is an annoying anti pattern and only going to cause you pain. Embrace full CJS or ESM.

Comment: @morganney, this leads to the same error: Property `Bar` is not declared configurable.

Comment: Have you tried using `jest.mock('./Bar')` instead? https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules